# Would it be possible to open a file on an external device without copying it in INetCache?

Tags: windows, shell, file, caching, copy

I'm writing a small image viewer application, which use the Shell API to access to the files.

I noticed that, every time I access an image on an external device, like my connected phone, the file is copied in a local cache, named INetCache.

Below is an example of an image path on my external device:

> This PC\Apple iPhone\Internal Storage\DCIM\202005__\IMG_2768.HEIC

and the same image path from the PIDL received by the Shell when I try to open it:

> C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE\MD7CNXNX\IMG_2768[1].HEIC

As you can see, the file was copied in the INetCache, and even duplicated. Would it be possible to open the file from my external device without copying it in the INetCache? And if yes, how may I achieve that (if possible using the Shell API)?

**UPDATE on 11.08.2022**

Below is the code I use to get the PIDL from an IDataObject I receive after a drag&drop operation, which contains the file to open:

```
std::wstring GetPIDLFromDataObject(IDataObject* pDataObject)
{
    std::wstring line = L"PIDL result:\r\n";

    if (!pDataObject)
        return line;

    CComPtr<IShellItemArray> pShellItemArray;

    if (FAILED(::SHCreateShellItemArrayFromDataObject(pDataObject, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pShellItemArray))))
        return line;

    CComPtr<IEnumShellItems> pShellItemEnum;
    pShellItemArray->EnumItems(&pShellItemEnum);

    if (!pShellItemEnum)
        return line;

    for (CComPtr<IShellItem> pShellItem; pShellItemEnum->Next(1, &pShellItem, nullptr) == S_OK; pShellItem.Release())
    {
        CComHeapPtr<wchar_t> spszName;

        if (SUCCEEDED(pShellItem->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING, &spszName)))
        {
            line += spszName;
            line += L"\r\n";
        }

        CComHeapPtr<ITEMIDLIST_ABSOLUTE> pIDL;

        if (SUCCEEDED(CComQIPtr<IPersistIDList>(pShellItem)->GetIDList(&pIDL)))
        {
            UINT  cb = ::ILGetSize(pIDL);
            BYTE* pb = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(static_cast<PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE>(pIDL));

            for (UINT i = 0; i < cb; i++)
            {
                WCHAR hexArray[4];

                ::StringCchPrintf(hexArray, ARRAYSIZE(hexArray), L" % 02X ", pb[i]);
                line += hexArray;
            }

            line += L"\r\n";
        }
    }

    return line;
}
```

Comment: How do you get the pidl? What do you mean by open, accessing as IStream?

Comment: Once you have the pidl, how do you open it?

Comment: @Anders I think that what I do with the PIDL after isn't relevant for the issue I mention above. The issue is that the data I extract from IDataObject, from which I get the PIDL, points to a file copied locally, while I expect an access to the source file on the external device, at least with a read-only access. My question was: Is there a way to avoid the local copy? (I.e. with or without using the Shell API, no matter which library or API is used)

Comment: I'd say debug the drag source to figure out when it makes the copy. Can you EnumFormatEtc without generating a copy? You must avoid CF_HDROP! You need an IStream from CFSTR_FILECONTENTS or CFSTR_SHELLIDLIST (via a Bind).

Comment: Or eliminate the dragging part and get an IShellItem for This PC\Apple iPhone\Internal Storage\DCIM\202005__\IMG_2768.HEIC and Bind to get an IStream, if that is not possible, d&d is probably not possible either...

Comment: The dragging part isn't what it seems to be here ;-) I need it because I declared my application as a COM drop target, which allows to associate file types without having to use the command line to achieve that. The background system which opens the file is based on the following article: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100503-00/?p=14183. So basically I just double-click on an image on my device, which redirect the file to open on my app. But As I said the received file seems to be a local copy when I open it from my external device.

Comment: Have you set UseUrl=0x1 in App Paths? And again, try binding for IStream without the dataobject just to make sure the Apple IShellFolder implementation can actually do this without a copy.